# Permission Denied in Cron Job

Tags: cron, nas

Super newb here, I am running an Ubuntu Server as a home NAS and everything is going well, i've created a bash script to download an XML TV guide from the internet for my PVR back-end, then move and extract it (zip file) on my network share. If I run the script via terminal everything works well, but I would like to set this up to run twice a day. When I tried to automate via a cron job, I got errors and its not working.

Here is my bash script which works I'm also not sure if this is an efficient way to do it.

```
#!/bin/bash
echo ""
echo "epg update"
echo ""
wget -r http://website.com/guide.zip
cd website.com
cp guide.zip /home/disk2/TEMP/
cd /home/disk2/TEMP/
unzip -o guide.zip
```

And when I setup a cron job via webmin to automate I got error permission denied. cannot file file.

Moreover, I don't get why it is ending up in a folder website.com, that wasn't my intention but I just went with it

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: How do you setup your cron job? Exactly for what you get permission error?

Comment: i was getting file/folder not found permission denied, changing the job to run as "root" user makes it work fine, it doesnt make sense to me i can run it as "user" via terminal, but if i run it as "user" via cron i get errors, is there any issues with just leaving it as running as "root"

Comment: RULE #1 of cron:  It runs in your `$HOME` directory.  So all file references should be fully-qualified.   --> when you say cd website.com it is going to /home/<username>/website.com, for instance.

Answer (score 1):

It creates the folder because you use the `-r` argument. You can leave that out if you don't want it in a folder.

Furthermore, it could be simplified:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo ""
echo "epg update"
echo ""
wget http://website.com/guide.zip
unzip -o guide.zip -d /home/disk2/TEMP/
```

If you still get the error, you might want to check if `/home/disk2/TEMP/` is the right directory. Normally this path would indicate you have a user named disk2.

Comment: thank you that looks better for sure, when i installed ubuntu i setup my storage drives to mount to /home/disk1 /home/disk2, /home/disk3 so i could setup SMB sharing,  Im a total newbie, so while it works, your probably like "what is this guy thinking"